# Issue while validating BASH Script

Tags: linux, bash

I have code lint errors while trying to validate my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    printf 'No arguments supplied. Available arguments: dev, production\n'

    exit 128
fi

if [ "$1" -ne "dev" ] || [ "$1" -ne "production" ]; then
    printf 'Unsupported arguments supplied. Supported arguments: dev, production\n'

    exit 128
fi

if [ "$1" -eq "dev" ]; then
    printf 'Test Server Deploy Started!\n\n' &&
elif [ "$1" -eq "production" ]; then
    printf 'Production Server Deploy Started!\n\n' &&
fi

printf "=====> [1/7] - Pull Submodules <=====\n\n" &&
git pull --recurse-submodules &&

printf "\n\n=====> [2/7] - Update Submodules <=====\n\n" &&
git submodule update --init --recursive --force &&

printf "\n\n=====> [3/7] - Stop All Servers <=====\n\n" &&
pm2 stop all &&

printf "\n\n=====> [4/7] - Install Frontend Node Modules <=====\n\n" &&
cd ./frontend &&

if [ "$1" -eq "dev" ]; then
    npm ci &&
elif [ "$1" -eq "production" ]; then
    npm ci --only=production &&
fi

printf "\n\n=====> [5/7] - Build Frontend <=====\n\n" &&
npm run build &&

printf "\n\n=====> [6/7] - Install Backend Node Modules <=====\n\n" &&
cd ../backend &&

if [ "$1" -eq "dev" ]; then
    npm ci &&
elif [ "$1" -eq "production" ]; then
    npm ci --only=production &&
fi

printf "\n\n=====> [7/7] - Start All Servers <=====\n\n" &&
cd .. &&

if [ "$1" -eq "dev" ]; then
    pm2 restart ./build/ecosystem.config.js --env dev --update-env &&
elif [ "$1" -eq "production" ]; then
    pm2 restart ./build/ecosystem-prod.config.js --env production --update-env &&
fi

printf "\n\nDone.\n"
exit 0;
```

I used https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check, but it seems error with if statement.

I'm waiting for param "dev" or "deployment".

errors below:

```
Line 15:
if [ "$1" -eq "dev" ]; then
^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this if expression.
                       ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this then clause. Fix to allow more checks.

Line 17:
elif [ "$1" -eq "production" ]; then
     ^-- SC1072: Unexpected keyword/token. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

Comment: `-eq` compares two integers, not strings.

Comment: Replace all `-eq` with `==`.

Comment: Use `set -e` to make the script error out if any command fails. A lot nicer than sprinkling `&&` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An earlier line:

```
if [ "$1" -ne "dev" ] || [ "$1" -ne "production" ]; then
```

will always be true. That should probably be

```
if [ "$1" != "dev" -a "$1" != "production" ]; then
```

@Andrea is also correct that the `&&`'s don't make sense

You would probably be better off using a case statement:

```
case "$1" in
  dev)
    echo "found dev"
    ;;
  production)
    echo "found production"
    ;;
  *)
    echo "not dev or prod, or not present"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: The `[` or `test` program should return with non-zero exit status greater then 1 on syntax error, which would result in the expression being always false. The second line of code is a syntax error.

Comment: @KamilCuk True, but the obvious intent of the line is also in error.

Answer (score 2):

You can just remove all those trailing `&&`. Example, from this:

```
printf 'Test Server Deploy Started!\n\n' &&
                                         ^^
```

to this:

```
printf 'Test Server Deploy Started!\n\n'
```

Comment: It is correct that these are what cause the syntax error, but using them to join statements on multiple lines is perfectly permissible and a common idiom. It's just that you can't join an `elif`.